# Bounded sequence in vector valued space

Tags: banach-spaces

I am working with a space of the form $E=L^{\infty}(0,\infty;X)$, where $X$ is a non reflexive Banach space.

If a sequence $(x_n)$ is bounded in $E$, how to extract a weakly converging subsequence?

I think that this is not always possible for an arbitrary Banach space $X$!

I tried to consider that $X$ has a separable dual and use Banach Alaoglu theorem, but I did not success to identify the dual of $E$.

What I am looking is to assume that $X$ satisfies a given property letting me extract a weakly converging subsequence.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean weak-* with respect to pairing L1 functions?

Comment: @LidingYao Yes that it

Comment: To be more precise. What I meant by a  subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ convege weakly to $x$, is for all $f\in E'$, $f(x_{n_k}) \to f(x)$ holds strongly.

Comment: No what you say is the weak convergent, not weak-* convergent. You need to consider both dual of L^infty and dual of X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you thought, this is indeed not always possible.

---

Since $X$ isn't reflexive, a classical consequence of the [Mackey-Arens theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mackey%E2%80%93Arens_theorem) gives you the existence of bounded subsets of $X$ which aren't weakly relatively compact in $X$ and the [Eberlein-Šmulian theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberlein%E2%80%93%C5%A0mulian_theorem) then gives you the existence of a bounded sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbf N}$ of elements of $X$ which has no weakly convergent subsequence.

For every $n\in\mathbf N$, let $x_n$ be (the equivalence class in $L^\infty(0,\infty;X)$ of ) the constant function on $(0,\infty)$ taking everywhere the value $y_n$. The sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbf N}$ is a bounded sequence of $L^\infty(0,\infty;X)$ and I will show that it has no weakly convergent subsequence.

Let's proceed by contradiction and suppose that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbf N}$ has a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbf N}$ which converges weakly to some $x_\infty\in L^\infty(0,\infty;X)$. By the [Lebesgue differentiation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem), $x_\infty$ has many Lebesgue points (maybe you only know this theorem for scalar functions, but the proof presented on the Wikipedia page can be adapted to the case of vector-valued functions without any major modification); let $t\in(0,\infty)$ be a Lebesgue point of $x_\infty$ and let
$$y_\infty=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac 1{2h}\int_{t-h}^{t+h}x_\infty(s)\,ds.$$
I will show that $(y_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbf N}$ converges weakly to $y_\infty$, which will be a contradiction because $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbf N}$ has no weakly convergent subsequence.

Let $g$ be a continuous linear functional on $X$. Let $\mathscr U$ be an [ultrafilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter) on $(0,t)$ such that $(0,h)\in\mathscr U$ for every $h\in(0,t)$. The linear functional
$$f:x\longmapsto\lim_{h,\mathscr U}\frac 1{2h}\int_{t-h}^{t+h}g(x(s))\,ds$$
on $L^\infty(0,\infty;X)$ can be easily checked to be well-defined and continuous. Moreover, because $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbf N}$ converges weakly to $x_\infty$ and $g(y_n)=f(x_n)$ for every $n\in\mathbf N\cup\{\infty\}$, we have
$$g(y_{n_k})=f(x_{n_k})\underset{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}f(x_\infty)=g(y_\infty),$$
which concludes.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I would like to ask if we consider changing the notion of weak convergence to weak* convergence. As we know, there exist non-reflexive spaces, e.g., [see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3763072/bounded-sequence-in-l-infty-has-weakly-convergent-subsequence)  for which any bounded sequence has a weak* converging subsequence. Is there anything we can assume on $X$ to guarantee that $E$ exhibits this property.

Comment: @elmas What comes to mind is if $X$ has the Radon-Nikodym property and is the dual of a *separable* Banach space $Y$, then $F=L^1(0,\infty;Y)$ is a *separable* Banach space whose dual can be identified with $E$ and so in this setting, the Banach-Alaoglu theorem + metrizability of bounded subset of $E$ for the weak* topology $\sigma(E,F)$ tell you that any bounded sequence of elements of $E$ has a subsequence that converges for the w* topology $\sigma(E,F)$.